# Trying to find a movie about UFO energy beings

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to find a movie I saw at least 30 years ago. It was about some scientists that find proof that UFOs exist. They have numerous close encounters with them and some people end up being injured in car crashes caused by the UFOs.  One person gets abducted by them. It turns out they are not alien vehicles, but energy beings from another universe. They are very curious and childlike and the harm they caused was unintentional. They movie foreshadows this by showing a number of scenes of kids catching and playing with insects.

Does anyone know what this is? IIRC it was probably made in the 70s or 80s and I think it may have been a made for tv production. Possibly from Canada.